# How does one Add a Partition to an Existing Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partition

Given a Partition Function (`MonthlyPartition(DateTime2)`), a Partition Scheme (`Logs_PartitionScheme`) using that function and a table (`Logs`) which needs that Partition applying to its `[DateTime]` field; how do I add the Partition to the table?

I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Logs
ADD PARTITION Logs_PartitionScheme
```

but just get this when I run it:

> Column, parameter, or variable #40: Cannot find data type Logs_PartitionScheme.

I think that's just trying to add a column named "PARTITION" to `Logs` with a type of `Logs_PartitionScheme`.  I also get the same thing if I replace `Logs_PartitionScheme` with `MonthlyPartition`.

Logs_PartitionScheme is as follows:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME CatLogs_PartitionScheme
AS PARTITION MonthlyPartition
ALL TO ([Primary])
```

MonthlyPartition is as follows:

```
DECLARE @partitionsTable dbo.VarCharCollectionTableType --User-Defined Table Type to hold a collection of VarChars.

INSERT INTO @partitionsTable
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(FORMAT(RY, '0000'), FORMAT(RM, '00'), '01')
FROM dbo.Logs

DECLARE @partitionsString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @partitionsString =
    CASE
        WHEN @partitionsString IS NULL
        THEN CONCAT('''', [Text], '''')
        ELSE CONCAT(@partitionsString, ', ''', [Text], '''')
    END
    FROM @partitionsTable
    ORDER BY [Text]

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX) =
(
    SELECT CONCAT
    (
        N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MonthlyPartition(DateTime2)
        AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
        (',
        @partitionsString,
        ')'
    )
)

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @statement
```

Comment: [ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You have to drop your clustered index and re-add it with `on partition Logs_PartitionScheme` clause

Comment: What clustered index?  I have one on the Primary Key (`Id`) field - that one?

Comment: Yeah...primary key probably s/b clustered...and any indexes using the primary key or partition column also need have `on partition...` added to the index.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling to get this to work!  I can't drop and re-add the clustered index because it's part of the primary key.  I've tried re-adding the primary key as non-clustered then creating a clustered index like so `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Logs_ParentEntityId_DateTime ON dbo.Logs ( ParentEntityId, [DateTime] ) PARTITION Logs_PartitionScheme` but I then just get: >Incorrect syntax near 'PARTITION'.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new partition, set the partition scheme next used filegroup to the desired one and `SPLIT` the function to create a new partition boundary for data on that filegroup. For example:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME Logs_PartitionScheme NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION MonthlyPartition() SPLIT RANGE('2019-05-01T00:00:00.0000000');
```

Comment: I'll include the definitions of `Logs_PartitionScheme` and `MonthlyPartition` in the question.  I don't think this code does what I need (which is to add the scheme or function to the table).